# ToolStripMenuItem ShowDropDown - event doesn't fire

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip, toolstripmenu

I want to put a context sensitive menu on the right-click of a DataGridView. I want to have a single menu item derived from the content of the clicked cell and a variable number of items in a sub-menu, retrieved from a database.

I do this by building the ToolStripMenuItem in the ContextMenuStrip Opening event. And it works - almost...

If I leave the sub-menu undisplayed so the user has to click the single item in the toplevel menu, everything is fine but if I call the ShowDropDown method to display the submenu automatocally, the exents don't fire when the items are clicked on.

Here's the simplest code I can produce to recreate the problem - I've pulled out all the references to the DataGridView and database so my "dynamic" menu is decidedly static ;-)

If you put this is a Form definition, right-click anywhere on the form and you'll see the working but not desired behaviour - click on a sub-menui tem and see a popup. Tick the checkbox and right-click again and you'll see the submenu flies out automatically - but clicking items won't fire the aliasClick handler.

Any thoughts? In this particular application, I can code a perfectly servicable workaround which avoids using ShowDropDown - but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong in case I need to use it in future.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ContextMenuStrip cms;
    private CheckBox chkAuto;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        chkAuto = new CheckBox();
        Controls.Add(chkAuto);

        cms = new ContextMenuStrip();
        cms.Opening += contextMenuStrip1_Opening;

        this.MouseClick += Form1_MouseClick;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            cms.Show(Cursor.Position);
    }

    private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        cms.Items.Clear();
        ToolStripMenuItem tsmi = new ToolStripMenuItem("Title from datagridviewcell");
        tsmi.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("First item from database lookup", null, aliasClick));
        tsmi.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Second item from database lookup", null, aliasClick));
        tsmi.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Last item from database lookup", null, aliasClick));
        cms.Items.Add(tsmi);
        if (chkAuto.Checked)
            tsmi.ShowDropDown();
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    private void aliasClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem clickedItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
        MessageBox.Show(clickedItem.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how to go about proving this, but I suspect that your call to `tsmi.ShowDropDown()` is somehow causing the coordinates to not be captured properly by the click handler.  Replace it with `cms.Show(MousePosition)` and it works.

Perhaps some useful info gleaned from a look at the coordinates...

```
var mi = new ToolStripMenuItem("First item from database lookup", null, aliasClick);
tsmi.DropDownItems.Add(mi);
var mi2 = new ToolStripMenuItem("Second item from database lookup", null, aliasClick);
tsmi.DropDownItems.Add(mi2);
var mi3 = new ToolStripMenuItem("Last item from database lookup", null, aliasClick);
tsmi.DropDownItems.Add(mi3);
cms.Items.Add(tsmi);
if (chkAuto.Checked)
    tsmi.ShowDropDown();
    //cms.Show(MousePosition);
Debug.WriteLine(mi.Bounds.ToString());
```

Comment: I've had a quick tinker but although `cms.Show()` does preserve the event handler, it doesn't (as far as I can tell) cause the sub-menu to open automatically. I suspect you're right about the coordinates - but I don't know what to do about it!

Comment: Curious.  In my test app, the menu opens as expected.

Comment: It'll open if you hover over the top-level item or click it, but for me it doesn't open otherwise. It may be easier to spot if you make the cms open away from the mouse: 

`private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
                cms.Show(new Point(Cursor.Position.X + 50, Cursor.Position.Y + 50));
        }` 

I've tried it at home on the free version of VS Express and at work on VS Pro 2015